# Trying to set CacheProvider.setCache(Cache cache) and got an error "Cache provider must be configured before cache is accessed."

Tags: java, caching, jsonpath, jayway

I am using **JsonPath** from jayway for reading the JSON object.

But whenever there is a concatenation operation it give me the cached value, below is the path:

```
$.concat($.clientservice.output.client.lgivname, ", " ,$.clientservice.output.client.lsurname)
```

and the Java function used is

```
Object data = JsonPath.read(<responseJson_changeson_every_request>, concatPath);
```

but it returns the **same value every time**. But I run this with different JSON so I am trying set cache to some empty object like below but got an error:

```
CacheProvider.setCache(new NOOPCache());
Object data = JsonPath.read(<responseJson_changeson_every_request>, concatPath);
```

Error message:

```
"Cache provider must be configured before cache is accessed."
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring boot, and if you want to initiate the CacheProvider object we have  to do it before the application is started. So i have created a bean class that will execute before starting the service or you can initiate CacheProvider object in the main method too.